# Extracting and Merge in R

Tags: r

Below is a list that I have:

```
V1        V2 
Zealous   Jane
Pretty    May
Smart     Kate
Place     China
```

Below is the data that I have:

```
Name     Source
JJ       Kate has a brother
Kl       May lives in China.
```

I would like to make use the list and data I have to extract the data that matches using R.

Below is the output I would like to get:

```
Name    Source                Words   Comments
JJ      Kate has a brother    Kate    Smart
Kl      May lives in China    May     Pretty
Kl      May lives in China    China   Place
```

Thank you.

Comment: post the output of dput.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Hi, what do you mean?

Comment: How you get the above list?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I created one.

Comment: that's what i'm saying `dput(list)`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Ok, thanks. I will try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str_extract` to extract the words from `df2` and the `match` the 'nm1' with 'V2' column of 'df1' to index the 'V1' column of 'df1'

```
library(stringr)
nm1 <- str_extract(df2$Source, paste(df1$V2, collapse='|'))
df2$Words <- df1$V1[match(nm1, df1$V2)]
df2
#  Name              Source  Words
#1   JJ  Kate has a brother  Smart
#2   Kl May lives in China. Pretty
```

#### Update

For the updated dataset ('df1'), we can use `str_extract_all` to extract multiple words in a `list`, `stack` it to convert to `data.frame`, `merge` with `df2` and `match` the 'values' column with 'V2' from 'df1' to create the 'Comments' column.

```
 nm1 <- str_extract_all(df2$Source, paste(df1$V2, collapse='|'))
 d1 <- stack(setNames(nm1, df2$Name))
 df2N <- merge(df2, d1, by.x='Name', by.y='ind')
 df2N$Comments <- df1$V1[match(df2N$values, df1$V2)]
 colnames(df2N)[3] <- 'Words'
 df2N
 #  Name              Source Words Comments
 #1   JJ  Kate has a brother  Kate    Smart
 #2   Kl May lives in China.   May   Pretty
 #3   Kl May lives in China. China    Place
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("Zealous", "Pretty", "Smart"), 
V2 = c("Jane", 
"May", "Kate")), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df2 <- structure(list(Name = c("JJ", "Kl"), 
Source = c("Kate has a brother", 
"May lives in China.")), .Names = c("Name", "Source"),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

#### Updated data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("Zealous", "Pretty", "Smart", "Place"), 
V2 = c("Jane", "May", "Kate", "China")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Alright sure, Would like to ask if this applies if there are more than 1 words from the data and the list?

Comment: @poppp It depends on how it occurs in the original dataset.

Comment: In that case use `str_extract_all` to get all the words in a `list`.  I will update shortly.